# How to include a value from jenkins console into email notification

Tags: hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have server start time printed in jenkin console something like:

```
12:43:09 1: inside loop waiting for login to be ready...
12:43:09 wget --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://localhost/webacs/pages/common/login.jsp
12:43:11 End time @: 2015-03-06 12:43:11 -0800
12:43:11 Start took 1920.088265 seconds!
12:43:11 Server Started in 00:32:00
12:43:11 service iptables save
```

How to include "Server Started in 00:32:00" details in editable email notification?

Comment: How automated do you want the process, and what exactly do you mean by and editable email notification?

Comment: Editable email notification is the plugin in jenkin used to send email notifications. I need to just be able to include a line from jenkin job console output into the email content.